# syntax for styling in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add 2 css styles with this line of jquery but can anyone tell me the proper syntax for separating them, right after the 0?

```
jQuery("nav").sticky({ topSpacing: 0; width: 100%});
```

Comment: What is "sticky"? What is "topSpacing"? Your question is not clear, as "sticky" is not a JQuery function, and "topSpacing" not a CSS rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `,` as its just a JavaScript object. You also need to put `100%` in quotes.

```
jQuery("nav").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, width: '100%'});
                                    ^ here   ^ here
```

Comment: thanks for help guys throw me some likes so I can break 15 and throw them back to yall.

Answer (score 2):

Its a simple JSON, separate it with comma[`,`] and also you need to specify the `100%` inside quotes.

```
jQuery("nav").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 , width: "100%"});
```

Comment: you should mention that you quoted the 100% value

Answer (score 1):

Looks like using this plugin. 
https://github.com/garand/sticky

Use ","(comma) instead of ";"semicolon. 
Thanks.

You can also look examples in the link